# What is the Memory RAM pin count for an Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory

For [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html), about the RAM is indicated

```
Supports 1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAM.
```

And for [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html), about the RAM is indicated

```
Supports 1600 MHz PC3-12800 DDR3L SDRAM SO-DIMMs (204-pin).
```

As you can see the latter indicates the pin count.

**Question**

- What is the Memory RAM pin count for an `Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

204-pin

See [here](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/apple/macbook-pro-(13-inch--early-2011)) or the image below.

[image]

Comment: Become familiar with EveryMac.com

Comment: @Alan: I have no idea what your previous comment means. Care to enlighten me? The OP has links to EveryMac.com in the question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for the reply ... I mostly wrote the OP because I thought that could exist some memory RAMs  based with the specs (8GB/DDR3/1333MHz) but with a different pin's number - I couldn't find something official from Apple. Thanks again

Comment: @DavidAnderson, Everyman.com is a website that has the technical specifications of... ...every Mac ever made.